# How to detect nested loop with same index in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint, syntax-checking

I am trying to detect nested loop with the same index which looks like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }
}
```

I have searched Eslint rules but haven't found any solution so far. Is there a way to detect this bad code smell? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't help trying to be humorous and pointing out that in that **particular** case, it won't matter, since the inner loop body will never run. ;-) (`i = 0; i < 0`...) **;-)**

Comment: Why is a nested loop considered a "bad code smell"? Or do you mean that the loops share variables?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Not nested loops per se, nested loops *with the same index variable*. The inner one will shadow the outer one. I could see the argument that this is asking for trouble. :-)

Comment: There is a lint rule for this https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow, I assume it would detect this case

Comment: @evolutionxbox - LOL, I just found that as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it was your use of shadow that reminded me of its existence

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hahaha that's true:-), thanks for reminding, corrected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESLint has the [`no-shadow` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) that would flag that up, as well as other places where you've shadowed an outer scope variable with an inner scope one. For example:

```json
{
    "no-shadow": ["error", { "builtinGlobals": false, "hoist": "functions", "allow": [] }]
}
```

[Demo on the ESLint site](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiZm9yKGxldCBpID0gMDsgaSA8IDEwOyBpKyspIHtcbiAgICBmb3IobGV0IGkgPSAwOyBpIDwgMTA7IGkrKykge1xuICAgICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyhpKTtcbiAgICB9XG59Iiwib3B0aW9ucyI6eyJwYXJzZXJPcHRpb25zIjp7ImVjbWFWZXJzaW9uIjoxMSwic291cmNlVHlwZSI6InNjcmlwdCIsImVjbWFGZWF0dXJlcyI6e319LCJydWxlcyI6eyJjb25zdHJ1Y3Rvci1zdXBlciI6MiwiZm9yLWRpcmVjdGlvbiI6MiwiZ2V0dGVyLXJldHVybiI6Miwibm8tYXN5bmMtcHJvbWlzZS1leGVjdXRvciI6Miwibm8tY2FzZS1kZWNsYXJhdGlvbnMiOjIsIm5vLWNsYXNzLWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tY29tcGFyZS1uZWctemVybyI6Miwibm8tY29uZC1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWNvbnN0LWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tY29uc3RhbnQtY29uZGl0aW9uIjoyLCJuby1jb250cm9sLXJlZ2V4IjoyLCJuby1kZWJ1Z2dlciI6Miwibm8tZGVsZXRlLXZhciI6Miwibm8tZHVwZS1hcmdzIjoyLCJuby1kdXBlLWNsYXNzLW1lbWJlcnMiOjIsIm5vLWR1cGUta2V5cyI6Miwibm8tZHVwbGljYXRlLWNhc2UiOjIsIm5vLWVtcHR5IjoyLCJuby1lbXB0eS1jaGFyYWN0ZXItY2xhc3MiOjIsIm5vLWVtcHR5LXBhdHRlcm4iOjIsIm5vLWV4LWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tZXh0cmEtYm9vbGVhbi1jYXN0IjoyLCJuby1leHRyYS1zZW1pIjoyLCJuby1mYWxsdGhyb3VnaCI6Miwibm8tZnVuYy1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWdsb2JhbC1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWlubmVyLWRlY2xhcmF0aW9ucyI6Miwibm8taW52YWxpZC1yZWdleHAiOjIsIm5vLWlycmVndWxhci13aGl0ZXNwYWNlIjoyLCJuby1taXNsZWFkaW5nLWNoYXJhY3Rlci1jbGFzcyI6Miwibm8tbWl4ZWQtc3BhY2VzLWFuZC10YWJzIjoyLCJuby1uZXctc3ltYm9sIjoyLCJuby1vYmotY2FsbHMiOjIsIm5vLW9jdGFsIjoyLCJuby1wcm90b3R5cGUtYnVpbHRpbnMiOjIsIm5vLXJlZGVjbGFyZSI6Miwibm8tcmVnZXgtc3BhY2VzIjoyLCJuby1zZWxmLWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tc2hhZG93LXJlc3RyaWN0ZWQtbmFtZXMiOjIsIm5vLXNwYXJzZS1hcnJheXMiOjIsIm5vLXRoaXMtYmVmb3JlLXN1cGVyIjoyLCJuby11bmRlZiI6Miwibm8tdW5leHBlY3RlZC1tdWx0aWxpbmUiOjIsIm5vLXVucmVhY2hhYmxlIjoyLCJuby11bnNhZmUtZmluYWxseSI6Miwibm8tdW5zYWZlLW5lZ2F0aW9uIjoyLCJuby11bnVzZWQtbGFiZWxzIjoyLCJuby11bnVzZWQtdmFycyI6Miwibm8tdXNlbGVzcy1jYXRjaCI6Miwibm8tdXNlbGVzcy1lc2NhcGUiOjIsIm5vLXdpdGgiOjIsInJlcXVpcmUteWllbGQiOjIsInVzZS1pc25hbiI6MiwidmFsaWQtdHlwZW9mIjoyLCJwcmVmZXItY29uc3QiOjIsIm5vLXNoYWRvdyI6Mn0sImVudiI6eyJicm93c2VyIjp0cnVlfX19):

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//          ^−−−−− 'i' is already declared in the upper scope on line 1 column 9.
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it, since it's pure logic